# Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authoriz (truncated...)

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.4, mailgun

I'm using mailgun to send email in Laravel and I don't know this error. I think I must verify domain?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up some [authorized recipients](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/217531258) for the sandbox domain?

https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/faqs.html#how-do-i-pick-a-domain-name-for-my-mailgun-account

> A sandbox subdomain of mailgun.org. Example: sandboxXX.mailgun.org.
>   This option allows for quick testing, without having to setup DNS
>   entries. This domain is provisioned automatically with every new
>   account. But you can send only to authorized recipients.